# Could you please tell me about the warning "telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.TakeoutInvalidError" while export Telegram chat history?

Tags: python, message, telethon

While I'm trying to export Telegram chat history, pycharm warning "telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.TakeoutInvalidError".

```
def chat_message_takeout(chat_id, client: TelegramClient, save_path: str, offset_date: datetime.datetime):
    with client.takeout() as takeout:
        messages = takeout.iter_messages(entity=chat_id, reverse=True, min_id=min_id, offset_date=offset_date)
        for message in messages:
            print(message, '\n')
```

How ever, the code once success,but report errors then.

```
File "C:/PycharmProjects/Telegram_chat_history_crowl/get_chat_hisroty.py", line 51, in main
    msg_tl.chat_message_takeout(XXXXXXXXXXX,
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\Telegram_chat_history_crowl\msg_tl.py", line 134, in chat_message_takeout
    print(message, '\n')
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\Telegram_chat_history_crowl\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\helpers.py", line 193, in _sync_exit
    return loop.run_until_complete(self.__aexit__(*args))
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\Telegram_chat_history_crowl\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\account.py", line 53, in __aexit__
    result = await self(functions.account.FinishTakeoutSessionRequest(
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\Telegram_chat_history_crowl\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\account.py", line 77, in __call__
    return await self.__client(
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\Telegram_chat_history_crowl\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 30, in __call__
    return await self._call(self._sender, request, ordered=ordered)
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\Telegram_chat_history_crowl\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 79, in _call
    result = await future
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.TakeoutInvalidError: The takeout session has been invalidated by another data export session (caused by InvokeWithTakeoutRequest)
```

Is that means a process is running on the telegram server, so that my request can't be accepted?Is there anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Clearing all storage / auth data of telethon and re-logging in to my account through the telethon CLI again worked for me.